# Maximal subset with given Hamming distances

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, metric-spaces, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose $A$ is a finite alphabet, $|A| = n$. Suppose $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let’s define the Hamming metric on $A^m$ as $d_m(a_1…a_m, b_1…b_m) = |\{i \leq m|a_i \neq b_i\}|$.

Now, let’s define $s(n, m, k)$ as the maximal possible cardinality of a subset $L \subset A^m$ such that $\forall u, v \in L$ either $u = v$ or $d_m(u, v) = k$.

Is there some sort of general formula for $s(n, m, k)$?

It is not hard to see, that $s(n, m , k) = 1$ for $k > m$. Also, $s(n, m, 1) = n^m$. However I do not know how to deal with $1 < k \leq m$.

EDIT:

There is also a probably relevant combinatorial theorem called **Singleton inequality** which states:

> Suppose $L \subset A^m$ such that $\forall u, v \in L$ either $u = v$ or $d_m(u, v) \geq k$. Then $|L| \leq |A|^{m - k + 1}$

However, I currently do not know, will it be useful to solve this problem or not...

Comment: I wonder whether this is not related to error-correcting codes, at least for $A = \{0, 1\}$.

Comment: Say that the elements of $A$ are $\{1, \dots, n\}$. Consider the map $f : A^m \to (\mathbb{R}^n)^m$ given by $(i_1, \dots, i_m) \mapsto (e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_m})$, where $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the standard basis vector with a $1$ in the $i$-th coordinate. It's not hard to show that $d_m(a, b) = \frac{1}{2}(d(f(a), f(b)))^2$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$. Thus if $L \subset A^m$ is equidistant, $f(L)$ is also equidistant. ...

Comment: ... But in fact the image of $f$ is contained in a subspace of dimension $(n-1)m$, (since it's contained in $(\Delta^n)^m$, where $\Delta^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the regular simplex). The maximal size of a set of equidistant points in this subspace is $(n-1)m + 1$, so $s(n, m, k) \leq (n-1)m + 1$.